# How to get Uri to Internal Storage DCIM?

Tags: android

I am building an application where I need to build my own custom Gallery.
But thing is my files are stored in the internal storage and not external storage
So the

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
```

is of not use cause I want the files on the internal DCIM.
I dont know how to access those files. Please Help

Comment: There is no "Internal Storage DCIM" in Android devices, at least from an Android SDK standpoint. Please edit your question and show your code where you are saving your images to your directory, so that we can understand exactly what location you are referring to.

Comment: I am not storing any images. See whatever photos we click by our Camera goes into a folder DCIM. I just want to get that Uri for the images of the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those images are on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) from the standpoint of the Android SDK. The best way to get to the directory will be through:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

[Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (app-only storage not directly accessible by the user) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) are different concepts.